# Displaying wind data from csv in back ground at point in Google map

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, google-maps-api-3, google-api

i have wind data in csv format like lat and long, wind speed, direction, temperature, i want to show this data in back ground of Google map and it should be like if i click at a given point on the map, it should popup the data of wind speed, direction etc, i can give an example link of the image how really it looks, please help me, i have all the wind data, to produce this data from nasa it took one year, but i am not able to complete this task..

http://wpcore.wpe.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/wind-navigator.png

Answer (score 2):

You should convert your collected data from CSV to a JS object (json to be precise). That way you could use it as an input directly on your code.

```
var WindCollection=[
    {name: 'Place 1', lat: 37.55,  lng:-90 , wind_speed:50, direction:'NW', temperature:'60'},
    {name: 'Place 2', lat: 36.15,  lng:-94 , wind_speed:45, direction:'N', temperature:'62'},
    {name: 'Place 3', lat: 36.12,  lng:-89 , wind_speed:55, direction:'SE', temperature:'59'}
    ];
```

then, you could iterate over that object and draw a marker on each loop

```
WindCollection.forEach(function(windplace) {
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat:windplace.lat, lng:windplace.lng}, clickable:true, map:map, animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP });
});
```

(the drop animation is just there for a dramatic entrance).

Now you'll have one marker at each of your data points (or windpoints).

Lastly, you can attach a listener to the markers to open an infowindow when clicked

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infolist=jQuery('<ul></ul>');
    for (attribute in windplace) {
        infolist.append('<li><b>'+attribute+'</b>: '+windplace[attribute]+'</li>');
    }
    infowindow.setContent('<div class="infowindow">'+infolist.html()+'</div>');
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

please note that this must be done in the same loop where you draw the marker, because the "windplace" variable has sense only inside that same iteration. If you need to use that info later, then you should make the marker inherit the windplace content, that way the marker will always carry its original info.

```
marker.windplace = windplace;
```

so you can get, for example, the value of `marker.windplace.wind_speed` afterwards.

Let's put all together

http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/a4bd1e692e2db3e1dfe0